# Dynamics CRM SDK : Batch update specific fields in entity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, bulkupdate

I am new to Dynamics CRM development. I want to batch update certain fields in Entity using Batch update method in Dynamics CRM Online.
I am using below code for performing batch update:

```
var multipleRequest = new ExecuteMultipleRequest()
{
    Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings()
    {
        ContinueOnError = false,
        ReturnResponses = true
    },
    Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection()
};

foreach (var entity in entities.Entities)
{
    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest { Target = entity };
    multipleRequest.Requests.Add(updateRequest);
}

ExecuteMultipleResponse multipleResponse = (ExecuteMultipleResponse)service.Execute(multipleRequest);
```

How can I specify only fields which I want to update instead of entire entity being updated?

Note: I have around 200,000 records to update using the above code. Currently it takes around 1.5 minute to update a single batch of 1000 records. So was thinking a way to update only required fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to look at the way how the EntityCollection `entities` is filled up. If retrieving using RetrieveMultiple, then Pull the minimal fields may be the native Name field & PK Id field will come by default. This way not the whole entity will be updated back.

Avoid using `AllColumns = true`. Use ColumnSet to get minimal fields needed for validation.

```
ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("field_needed"),
```

Next, assign only the necessary fields like below inside loop.

```
foreach (var entity in entities.Entities)
    {
        UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest { Target = entity };

        entity.Attributes["field_to_update"] = "field_value";

        multipleRequest.Requests.Add(updateRequest);
    }
```

My answer will help you to understand what went wrong & correcting it. Like Nicknow said, you can assign fresh entity to solve issue.

Answer (score 8):

My recommended approach is to create a `new Entity()` object for the update. This way your update code doesn't need to worry about what fields were retrieved, it just takes the ones it cares about updating.

```
foreach (var entity in entities.Entities)
{
    var newEntity = new Entity(entity.LogicalName, entity.Id);

    //Populate whatever fields you want (this is just an example)
    newEntity["new_somefield"] = entity.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_somefield").ToUpper();

    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest { Target = newEntity };
    multipleRequest.Requests.Add(updateRequest);
}
```

Comment: Can anybody provide me an example of the SOAP body for executemultiplerequest? I don't know c#

Comment: @utkarsh2k2 - Please post a new question. This is not an appropriate request in a comment to an answer.

Comment: Here is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021029/soap-request-to-update-multiple-records-in-microsoft-dynamics-365-crm/53023907#53023907

Comment: Thanks Arun. Saved me some time.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way you can update only fields without updating the `Entity`**. So even to update a single field you need to create an entity with `Id` and set an attribute value and then create an `UpdateRequest` setting the entity as `Target` and then after update the `modifiedon` date changes to the time of update.

There is already codes in other answers telling how to create that but, you can also do `Entity.Attributes.Add("name", "vinod");`
to add a new field value. For your case since it is an update you probably have the entity object with you, so you can simply try to remove other fields as `Entity.Attributes.Remove("name");` if you have not put a filter while fetching and you have all the fields.

To update multiple records you simply need to have `Entity.LogicalName`,`Entity.Id` and the update field values and send it to the `UpdateRequest`. and please note without an `Entity.Id` it will try to create it.

But 200,000 records is too much and **I won't suggest using API rather do Excel data import as it is designed for data import.**