# Dynamics CRM & .NET (C#) Set field value for all rows

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-sdk

With the help of the `OrganizationService`, I want to give the value of a particular column the same value for each row in a table (with a condition). How do I do that all at once?

This is how I should do it in SQL:

```
UPDATE [XXX]
SET Status = "Draft"
WHERE parentId = 1
```

Comment: Using OrganizationService you can make changes to a specific entity only. You need to go for custom implementation.

Comment: The only way to do it through OrganisationService in a faster way is using ExecuteMultiple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no equivalent CRM SDK code to do it like your sample SQL. Because each CRM record update has to go through either `service.Update()` method or `UpdateRequest`.

[Refer this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47517206)  for execution of bulk requests using `ExecuteMultipleRequest`

Answer (score 0):

This is not an official way but you can set status or other optionset field with numbers in sql.
If you want to see the value of options set you must go to dynamics crm customization and see that.